# Calculate 2D XY point on a curved/warped 3D paraboloid plane

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I'm currently creating a custom 3D paraboloid mesh by warping a 2D plane with the following algorithm applied to each vertex:

```
function transformVertex(v) {
  var lat = toRad(v.y - height/2),
      lon = toRad(v.x - width/2)/cos(lat);
  lat = lat*cos(lon/1.5);
  v.x = radius * cos(lat) * cos(lon);
  v.y = radius * cos(lat) * sin(lon);
  v.z = radius * sin(lat);
}
```

My question is, how can I reverse this process? I need to take a 3D point on the paraboloid and convert it to 2D coordinates relative to that plane PRE warping.

Answer (score 1):

There are some changes in variables during calculation, so let's version the variables and determine their functional relationships:

```
1- lat_0 = f(v_0.y)
2- lon_0 = f(v_0.x, lat_0)
3- lat_1 = f(lat_0, lon_0)

4- v_1.x = f(lat_1, lon_0)
5- v_1.y = f(lat_1, lon_0)
6- v_1.z = f(lat_1)
```

Now going from 6 back to 1,

```
lat_1 = asin(v_1.z / radius)
lon_0 = asin(v_1.y / radius / cos(lat_1)) OR lon_0 = acos(v_1.x / radius / cos(lat_1))
```

At this point, lon_0 depends on v_0.x and lat_0, and lat_0 depends on v_0.y, which locks up the whole thing. It looks irreversible.

Comment: That was insightful, thank you for outlining the process that you took to figure this. Is there anything I can do to make this algorithm reversible? Or perhaps another method I could employ to generate the relative 2D coords?

Comment: If you're in such a need, storing both the transformed and original data in a struct would be a reasonable approach i think. It would also save you all the trouble with (perhaps expensive?) inverse trigonometric functions.

Comment: Duh! Why didn't I think of that? Thanks :)